# IntelliJ IDEA can't move multiple Kotlin classes

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

When I try to move multiple Kotlin classes in IDEA or Android Studio (macOS Catalina), I get error "Can't move from multiply source files"

Comment: Found bug in JetBrains youtrack - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-35235

Comment: I have the same error in refactor process.